# Is it possible to have my Flutter app run server-side Typescript/Javascript code?

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I spent a few months building an android app from scratch when I stumbled onto Flutter. Seems pretty useful, so I started to remake my app with it. Seems easy enough to understand and it does simplify everything, but I don't want all the server side code I wrote to go to waste. Is it possible to have my flutter app call and return values from the TS/JS code I wrote (currently on my local machine)?

For reference, I know I'm able to update Firestore using code directly in my flutter app, per the docs (example below). But I'd rather do as much processing on the server side as possible and only call functions/interpret the results on the client side. How can I call TS/JS functions from my flutter app?

```
Future updateUserData(String val) async {
    return await COLLECTION.document(uid).setData({
        name: val,    
    });
}
```

Comment: What you are talking about is Cloud functions. It allows you to call deployed functions directly from your app or with https; [link](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions)

Comment: Sounds like the start of a great answer @HamdamMuqimov ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/products/functions?gclid=Cj0KCQjwm9yJBhDTARIsABKIcGYgCnigoBmrGgKd3m5CI7p55kpuL8IcgrzEwH4FrbKTjr49dMKaTTkaAswDEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds). It's like a backend for your app where you can run code triggered by different event you can define like something changing in a database, crone job and even by directly calling them. With those you can directly call we have two different types [HTTP Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) and [Callable Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).

If you plan to call your functions only trough your App I would always recommend to use the `Callable Functions` because they work only trough your App and you also get the auth data in the functions `context`.